# Problem with types in a definition in lean

Tags: lean

If I make the definition

```
definition f (x : nat) := λ m, x + m
```

then `#check f` returns `f:nat -> nat -> nat`, as expected.

If instead I try to define

```
definition f (x : nat) : nat -> nat -> nat := λ m, x + m
```

then Lean complains, and that x has type `nat` but is expected to have type `nat -> nat`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically three ways of defining `f`

`def f (x m : nat) : nat := x + m`

`def f (x : nat) : nat -> nat := λ m, x + m`

`def f : nat -> nat -> nat := λ x m, x + m`

The type of all three of these `f`s is the same, there is simply different syntax for defining the function. Everything to the left of the colon is an input to the function, and after the colon is the return type. The term right of the `:=` should have the type after the colon. In your second example, the type of the term after the `:=` is `nat -> nat`, but the expected type is `nat -> nat -> nat`, because that's what was written after the colon. So there was an error.

All of the arguments left of the colon are included in the type of `f` if you type `#check f`.

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought that I should be giving the overall type of what I'm defining, but the first ```nat``` is of course already built into specifying the argument.